# How to get item id from cosine similarity matrix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, machine-learning, cosine-similarity

I am using Spark Scala to calculate cosine similarity between the Dataframe rows.

Dataframe schema is below:

```
root
    |-- itemId: string (nullable = true)
    |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

Sample of the dataframe below

```
    +-------+--------------------+
    | itemId|            features|
    +-------+--------------------+
    | ab    |[4.7143,0.0,5.785...|
    | cd    |[5.5,0.0,6.4286,4...|
    | ef    |[4.7143,1.4286,6....|
    ........
    +-------+--------------------+
```

Code to compute the cosine similarities:

```
val irm = new IndexedRowMatrix(myDataframe.rdd.zipWithIndex().map {
      case (row, index) => IndexedRow(row.getAs[Vector]("features"), index)
}).toCoordinateMatrix.transpose.toRowMatrix.columnSimilarities
```

In the irm matrix, I have (i, j, score) where i, j are the indexes of item i, and j of my original dataframe.
What I would like is to get (itemIdA, itemIdB, score) where itemIdA and itemIdB are the ids of index i and j respectively, by joining this irm with the initial dataframe or if there is any better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a row index before converting the dataframe to a matrix and create a mapping between the index and the id. After the computation, use the created `Map` to convert the column index (previously row index but changed with the `transpose`) to the id.

```
val rdd = myDataframe.as[(String, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)].rdd.zipWithIndex()
val indexMap = rdd.map{case ((id, vec), index) => (index, id)}.collectAsMap()
```

Calculate the cosine similarities as before using the :

```
val irm = new IndexedRowMatrix(rdd.map{case ((id, vec), index) => IndexedRow(index, vec)})
  .toCoordinateMatrix().transpose().toRowMatrix().columnSimilarities()
```

Convert column indices back to the ids:

```
irm.entries.map(e => (indexMap(e.i), indexMap(e.j), e.value))
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I had already thought about this solution but collectAsMap() is not recommened to use for large dataset which is my case: this method should only be used if the resulting data is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver’s memory.

Comment: @proximator: How large dataset are we talking about here? Only the id and index columns are collected  so it's as little as possible. If the data is of the size that you cannot collect these two columns to the driver you probably should not use `columnSimilarity` which will involve matrix multiplication.

Comment: will this map be in each node of my cluster? or shared?

Comment: @proximator: It will actually be shipped together with the task. It's possible to have a cached copy on each node by using `broadcast`.

Comment: @proximator You could also use two joins by using the index as join column. I'm guessing that it would be slower but could be worth a try. Then you do not need to collect the `indexMap` but keep it as an rdd/df.